# Postgresql - Having a portable database on an external hard drive usable by many computers

Tags: postgresql, ssd

I want to know if it is possible to have a portable Postgresql database on an external hard drive. The idea is to use that hard drive, by plugging it to one of my computers and use the database.

*For the moment, it is not possible for me to have a computer that is always running and connecting to it through the network. For some reasons I don't always have access to the same computer but I always have access to my external hard drive. The computers are both running a Linux distribution.*

Comment: Database != File 
A PostgreSQL cluster is a running process that manages its own files.  
You would have to have *exactly* the same Postgres software version running on both machines and would have to shut the database down /cleanly/ before unplugging/ejecting the external drive - every single time.  Failure to do so could completely trash your database.  Take backups very, /very/ often.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the machines that you want to use are running the exact same versions of the same operating system on the same architecture (hint: the C library must be the same version to avoid index corruption), that is no problem.  Simply create a data directory on the external drive with `initdb`. Make sure that the drive is reliable hardware and you are running a reliable file system on it.

Comment: I would add: make sure you always shut down Postgres properly before shutting down the computer or unplugging the drive.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea, although PostgreSQL should have no problem recovering from a crash.